# SQL Server - LAG(field1 + field2) function giving unwanted results

Tags: function, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query that will keep a rolling sum of the 2 fields from the previous record.  My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT [NC_GROUP]
  ,[NC_COVCAT]
  ,[NC_POST_DTE]
  ,[NC_GRP_SIZE]
  ,CASE
        WHEN (rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP])) LIKE LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP]))) OVER (order by [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] ) 
        AND rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT])) LIKE LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT]))) OVER (order by [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] ))
        THEN
            LAG([NC_PREV_PD_PREM] + [NC_CURR_PD_PREM]) OVER (ORDER BY [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT])
        ELSE
            [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
   END [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
  ,[NC_CURR_PD_PREM]
FROM [DBO].[Database]
order by [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT]
```

The logic runs through my table seen below, checking if the current record has the same group and category as the previous record, then SET the current [NC_PREV_PD_PREM] to the sum of the last records [NC_PREV_PD_PREM] and [NC_CURR_PD_PREM] values.

[image: The table before]

The query I linked above is giving me the following results:
[image: The current results - wrong]
Notice that the query is only adding for the second entry in each [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] grouping. The records afterwards are not being processed with the same logic.  I am unsure of how to proceed.

My desired results are the following picture:
[image: The desired results]

I am new to the LAG function/OVER clause and I am wondering if I am missing something with it.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not using the Partition by clause and also the order by clause is not correct

You may try this ...

LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP]))) OVER (**Partition By [NC_GROUP]** order by **some column which defines the ordering of records within this partition**)

As you are Partitioning on NC_GROUP and NC_COVCAT you will always get the NC_GROUP = Prev_NC_GROUP 
and [NC_COVCAT]=[Prev_NC_COVCAT]

Try this:

```
SELECT 
[NC_GROUP],[NC_COVCAT],[NC_POST_DTE],[NC_GRP_SIZE],
Case When [NC_GROUP]=[Prev_NC_GROUP] and [NC_COVCAT]=[Prev_NC_COVCAT] Then [Prev_NC_PREV_PD_PREM]+[Prev_NC_CURR_PD_PREM]
Else [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
End as [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
 FROM (
SELECT [NC_GROUP]
      ,[NC_COVCAT]
      ,[NC_POST_DTE]
      ,[NC_GRP_SIZE]
      ,LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP]))) OVER (Partition By [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] order by [id] ) [Prev_NC_GROUP]
      ,LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT]))) OVER (Partition By [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] order by [id] ) [Prev_NC_COVCAT] 
      ,LAG([NC_PREV_PD_PREM]) OVER (Partition By [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] order by [id]) [Prev_NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
      ,LAG([NC_CURR_PD_PREM]) OVER (Partition By [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] order by [id]) [Prev_NC_CURR_PD_PREM]
      ,[NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
      ,[NC_CURR_PD_PREM]
FROM [DBO].[Database] ) X
```

Comment: I agree with you about the bad using of over.

Comment: I tried this: `rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT])) LIKE LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT]))) OVER (partition by [NC_GROUP] ORDER BY [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] , [NC_COV_FR_DT], [NC_COV_TO_DT] )` and got the same results.  Did you mean for the when clause or the then?

Comment: The columns which you are using in Order by clause , should be able to recognize the next or prev record. I would suggest to create unique column like id or something, if there is not one. and use that in order by clause

Comment: I created an ID column that is auto-incremented.  I still haven't gotten it to work, but I currently have this:  `CASE
   WHEN (rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP])) LIKE LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_GROUP]))) OVER (partition by [NC_GROUP] ORDER BY [NC_COVCAT] )  
   AND rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT])) LIKE LAG(rtrim(ltrim([NC_COVCAT]))) OVER (partition by [NC_GROUP] ORDER BY [NC_COVCAT]))
   THEN
    LAG([NC_PREV_PD_PREM] + NC_CURR_PD_PREM) OVER (partition by [NC_GROUP], [NC_COVCAT] ORDER BY [id])
   ELSE
    [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]
    END [NC_PREV_PD_PREM]`

Comment: This is very close, but it doesn't calculate properly.  It does not take into account, the updates "rolling" total from the last row calculated.  After I update the previous row, I should use that new sum from the previous_prev_pd_prem, not the original previous paid prem